# Enter email address and phone number before accessing survey

Tags: joomla, survey

I am new in joomla 1.5 .
I am trying to implement a survey form. If the user is not a registered user then he or she can access the survey form after providing his or her email address and phone number. Else if the user is a registered user then he/she can get the access the survey form directly, no need to provide the email or phone number. Then according to that survey admin can interact with him / her through that email id or phone number.
How shall I progress according to this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//detect if a user entity exists in the session:
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) { //this is a registered user
  //redirect to the survey page
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/your-survey');
}
else{
  //display a form
  //with email & phone number
}
```